How to listen to the `popstate` event in a NextJS App Router project
I'm developing a Next.js application using the App Router.
I want to listen to the popstate event and call the preventDefault method on the event object to display the browser warning popup before the user navigates back.
However, the popstate event seems to be consumed by Next.js's routing system, and it's not fired when the user presses their browser's back button.
In Next.js's Pages Router, the router object (obtained via useRouter) exposed a beforePopState method. However, the App Router's router object doesn't have such a method.
Another related event, beforeunload, can't be relied upon either, as it's only triggered when navigating away from the Next.js application, not during back navigation within the single-page application.
How can I listen to the popstate event (i.e., back navigation event) in a Next.js App Router application?

Looks like this is not possible by design, here I share an issue posted on the Next.js repo with the details https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49532



import { useEffect } from 'react';

function useCustomPopstate() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePopState = (event) => {
      const confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to go back?';
      
      const userConfirmed = window.confirm(confirmationMessage);
      
      if (!userConfirmed) {

        window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location.href);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
    };
  }, []);
}

export default function MyComponent() {
  useCustomPopstate();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}




OP wanted to prevent default, won't this just navigate forth and back polluting the history?

This wont work in Nextjs app router, the original question explained why, this works only for not next.js/react apps.
